# Why do Entity Framework classes need a virtual member of an unrelated class

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Easier to show by example -- I'm using code-first to construct a database.  I have the following classes:

```
public class Blog
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public string BlogCode
        {
            get
            {
                return Title.Substring(0, 1) + ":" + AuthorName.Substring(0, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
```

I don't understand why Post needs a public virtual Blog Blog.  Does it act as a foreign key in the database to link back to the Blog?  It seems like if that were the case you would use the Blog Id.

Comment: If it is anything like NHibernate, the need for `virtual` is because a dynamic proxy is created that `override`s the member to provide a lazy-load feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does allow the two tables to be related and places a foreign key on `Post` relating to `Blog`.

Having `public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }` allows you to reference the `Blog` object from a `Post` object and then get access to all the properties of the `Blog`.  E.g. `myPost.Blog.Id`  If it used `public virtual int BlogId { get; set; }`, you would not be able to do this since `BlogId` would just be an `int` value.

If your domain objects are [lazy loaded](http://techblog.treenodes.com/index.php/2012/06/26/understanding-lazy-loading-eager-loading-and-explicit-loading-with-entity-framework-implementation/), `myPost.Blog` will not actually be hydrated with data from the database (i.e. no call to the `Blog` table) until that property is used.  As soon as it is used, Entity Framework will make the database call for you and hydrate the object with data from the `Blog` table.  This is part of the beauty of using an ORM... it allows you to focus on the code while it takes care of the database operations.

Comment: This actually has some interesting performance implications. If you *know* you're going to be using your navigation property you can get better performance by disabling lazy loading. Instead of potentially many round trips to the DB, you make one. In other cases where you may only occasionally (or not at all) make use of the data, then lazy loading can help mitigate the cost of loading data you don't need. Of course, you should always strive to do something like `select new { your_data_here }`, but that's not always possible.